# с++ класс не содержит члена; аргумент несовместим с параметром

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

Пытался подправить ошибки самостоятельно, но пока что безуспешно

А вот, собственно, сами ошибки :

E0135   class "Practform::MyForm" не содержит члена "draw_wrapper"

E0167   аргумент типа "Practform::MyForm ^" несовместим с параметром типа "void *"

Сразу приведу полный(не совсем так..только необходимый) листинг программы.

Буду благодарен за помощь

таймер:

```
    #pragma once
    #ifndef TIMERHPP
    #define TIMERHPP
    #include <chrono>
    #include <functional>
    class Timer1 {
    public:
        void add(std::chrono::milliseconds delay,
            std::function<void(void*)> callback,
            void* user_data_ptr,
            bool asynchronous = true);
    };
    #endif

#include "timer.h"
#include <thread>
Timer1::Timer1() {
}
void Timer1::add(std::chrono::milliseconds delay,
    std::function<void(void*)> callback,
    void* user_data_ptr,
    bool asynchronous) {
    if (asynchronous) {
        std::thread([=]() {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));
            callback(user_data_ptr);
            }).detach();
    }
    else {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));
        callback(user_data_ptr);
    }
}
```

сама программа:

```
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    
        [STAThreadAttribute]
        void main(array<String^>^ args)
        {
            Application::EnableVisualStyles();
            Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Practform::MyForm form;
            Application::Run(% form);
        
        }
        
        class MyForm {
        public:
        
            void draw1();
        
            static System::Void draw_wrapper(void* object) {
                reinterpret_cast<MyForm*>(object)->draw1();
            }
        
        
        };
         System::Void Practform::MyForm::draw1() {
             // Timer1 timer;
        
             int unit = 35;
             int pW = pictureBox1->Width;
             int pH = pictureBox1->Height;
        
             Bitmap^ img = gcnew Bitmap(pW, pH); 
        
             Graphics^ g = Graphics::FromImage(img); 
        
             for (int i = 0; i < pW; i += unit)
        
                 g->DrawLine(Pens::LightGray, i, 0, i, pH);
             for (int i = 0; i < pH; i += unit)
                 g->DrawLine(Pens::LightGray, 0, i, pW, i);
        
             Pen^ BlackPen = gcnew Pen(Brushes::Black);
             BlackPen->Width = 3.0F;
             int mX = int(pW / 2 - pW / 2 % unit);
             int mY = int(pH / 2 - pH / 2 % unit);
             g->DrawLine(BlackPen, mX, 0, mX, pH);
             g->DrawLine(BlackPen, 0, mY, pW, mY);
        
             g->ScaleTransform(1, -1); 
        
             g->TranslateTransform((float)mX, -(float)mY); 
        
             float x1 = -7.5f, x2 = 7.5f, s = 0.2f;
             float x = x1; 
             float y;
        
             System::Collections::Generic::List<PointF>^ ponts = gcnew System::Collections::Generic::List<PointF>(); 
        
             while (x < x2)
             {
        
        
                 y = (double)fcnPtr(x);
        
                 ponts->Add(PointF(x * (double)unit, y * (double)unit)); 
        
                 x += s;
        
             }
        
             g->DrawLines(Pens::Green, ponts->ToArray()); 
             
             delete g; 
        
             this->pictureBox1->Image = img; 
         }

 System::Void Practform::MyForm::draw_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
 {
      Timer1 timer;
      //MyForm MyFormobj;
    
      timer.add(std::chrono::milliseconds(500), &MyForm::draw_wrapper, this);
 }
```